# changing view while xml parsing in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

i have some problem with changing UIView on main thread.

i want to show xml parsing percentage in my view. on parsing it initializes value to mylabel.text and shows it in console but does not show in view. when parsing finishes it shows the last value of parsing in my label.

i know it is main thread problem that the main queue is using by xml parsing. how to stop xml parsing and make uilabel show the percentage in main thread? or any idea to show xml parsing percentage?
i'm using delegate method to show parsing process. here is my code:

//in **viewcontroller.h**

```
      #import "TheParser.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <TheParserProtocol> {
    BOOL YN;
   }
    ...

   }
```

// **viewcontroller.m**

```
  - (IBAction)updatePage:(id)sender {

      NSString *path = [[[NSBundle      mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files.xml"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data ];
    TheParser *theParser = [[TheParser alloc] initParser];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:theParser ];
    theParser.delegate = self;
    [xmlParser parse];


     }

     -(void) sendmes:(NSString *)str{
    UrlText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",str];
        NSLog(@" UrlText.text is %@", UrlText.text);
    }
```

//**my parser class**

// in TheParser.h my protocol

```
   @protocol TheParserProtocol 

      -(void) sendmes : (NSString *) str;

      @end
```

//in **TheParser.m**

```
  -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString: @"files"]) {
        app.ListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"file"]){
        theList = [[List alloc]init];
        int idValue = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
        [_delegate sendmes:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",idValue]];   

  ....

  }
```

i have checked

```
   [_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendmes:) withObject: [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"Last %i",i] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"works");
                    [_delegate sendmes:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];

                });
```

none worked for me.

can anybody help, please?

thanks, in advance

Comment: NSLog(@" UrlText.text is %@", UrlText.text); what it gives?

Comment: it gives the parameter what i want to show. but in view it does nothing

Comment: try [UrlText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",str]];

Comment: You know what the problem is, just run the parser on a background thread...

Comment: i've also tried it. it still doesnt work

Comment: @Wain I have a question. parser is on main thread. [txtFeild setText:] will also be called on main thread no? I really dont understand this threads. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Durgaprasad, I've added an answer to elaborate

Comment: try this.[_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendmes:) withObject: [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"Last %i",i] waitUntilDone:NO];   make waitUntilDone:yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the parsing and all of the UI Updates you're trying to make are both on the main thread, so the parsing is blocking the UI updates. The solutions you have tried currently result in a number of UI updates queued on the main thread and waiting for the parse to finish. These updates are then all processed too quickly to be shown on screen.

Rather than trying to make everything work on the main thread (not possible without significant and pointless changes to the parser) you should run the parse on a background thread and send the UI updates back to the main thread. You already have half the code for that. You just need to wrap the parsing in a block and run it in the background.

To be clear, you can't update the UI from the background thread so you do need to push the UI updates back onto the main thread.

---

There appears to be another issue, which is why there is so much confusion I think...

You're creating `theParser` to act as the delegate for your parser, but its never retained. Assuming you're using ARC, it's going to be released almost immediately so none of the delegate message will get forwarded to your view controller.

Comment: logically when this call is made "[_delegate sendmes:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",idValue]]; ". main thread should finish sendmes call and then should continue with parsing. But it seems this call is kept on hold. Why?

Comment: you mean 
     [xmlParser performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parse) withObject:nil];
  


 and  

      [_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendmes:) withObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last %i",i] waitUntilDone:NO];
  i've tried it. still does not work

Comment: @Durgaprasad, the message isn't on hold, it is sent and received. The log will work, and UI update won't. The label would be updated, but the new value wouldn't be rendered to the screen.

Comment: @aygul, yes, in its simplest form that should work. Noticed another issue though...

Comment: @wain k. thanks. what if wait UntilDone:yes? will it render data to screen?

Comment: @Durgaprasad, no, that would just lead to deadlock with the main thread waiting for the main thread (depending on how the method has been implemented). The update to the UI is on a later iteration of the run loop.

Comment: Retain (store in a property) `theParser` while the parse operation is in progress and run the parse on a background thread should work.

Comment: yes, retaining is the solution. thanx a million, sir! u saved my time  :)